# Usar objetos como propiedades de otra clase Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Soy nuevo en Swift, tengo una clase que tiene como propiedades otros objetos que pertenecen a otras clases.

```
class Pizza {
    var tamaño=Tamaño.self
    var masa=Masa.self
    var queso=Queso.self
    var ingredientes = [Ingrediente]()
    var aa:String = ""
}
```

El problema es que no puedo asignarles valores, me da el siguiente error " Cannot assign value of type 'Tamaño' to type 'Tamaño.Type'"

```
var pi:Pizza=Pizza()
var t:Tamaño=Tamaño(nombre: "min", precio: 25)
pi.tamaño=t
```

Cuando es otro tipo de dato como Int, String o un Struct sí que me deja pero cuando son objetos de una clase que yo me he creado no me deja.
¿Swift lo permite? 
¿Cuál es mi fallo? 
¿Solo puedo hacerlo con Struct?
Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Con la propiedad aa funciona correctamente porque has determinado que es de la clase String y le has dado un valor String, pero en las otras propiedades le has dado como valor una clase en vez de un objeto, por eso después da error al intentar asignarle como valor un objeto. Con : determinas la clase y con = asignas el valor

```
class Pizza {
    var tamano : Tamano?
    var masa : Masa?
    var queso : Queso?
    var ingredientes : Ingrediente?
    var aa : String = ""
}
```